# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res.data'). What is this?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux, firebase-authentication

I need to post data from a user to my database (firebase), but when I click on Touchable Opacity, my app returns this error:
Single Ocurrence
Possible Unhandled Promise rejection (id:0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res.data'

My code:

```
import {USER_LOGGED_IN, USER_LOGGED_OUT } from './actionTypes'
import axios from 'axios'

const authBaseURL ='https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty'
const API_KEY ='my api key is here'

export const login = user => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOGGED_IN,
    payload: user
  }
} 
export const logout = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOGGED_OUT
  }
}

export const createUser = user => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post (`${authBaseURL}/signupNewUser?key=${API_KEY}`, {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      returnSecureToken:true
    })
     .catch(err => console.log(err))
     .then (res => {
       if (res.data.localId) {
         axios.put(`/users/${res.data.localId}.json`, {
           name: user.name,
           tipouser: user.tipouser,
           telcelular: user.telcelular,
           telfixo: user.telfixo,
           facebookuser: user.facebookuser,
           instagramuser: user.instagramuser

         })
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
          .then(res => {
            console.log('Usuário criado com sucesso')
          })
       }
     })
  }
}
```

react-native: 0.60.4
axios: 0.19.0
react-redux: 7.1.1
redux: 4.0.4"

Comment: It means that `res.data` is `undefined`. Is seems the response you get doesn't have a `data` property.

Comment: console log res and see what is in there, if anything.  You may have to JSON.stringify it.

Comment: @mediaguru I assume you mean `JSON.parse`.

Comment: No.  try something like console.log('Results: ' + JSON.stringify(res));

Comment: Put that inside your .then where res should exist.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am following a course I have acquired. The instructor didn't add this 'res' anywhere, however, his application works normally.